# Add claims on successful login and retrieve it elsewhere in the application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

Please I need assistance in implementing a custom way of assigning claims to authenticated users.
On successful login,

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                //Get the user
                ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
                //Ends here
                ClaimsIdentity identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);
```

I use the userId to fetch the role and other information about the user from the datastore. Thereafter, I need to add claims about the user with those information such as email, role, firstName, Lastname, gender, etc. before redirecting to the user dashboard.
This is the way I try to do it but the problem is that even after adding the claims at the login method, I am not able to retrieve it at the _loginPartial razor view

For instance when I want to display the email claim value at the login partial like this

```
var claims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims;
    var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    var email = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

It returns null.

So, as a result, I can only access them on the same login method after adding them but I need to be able to access it from anywhere in the application. 
Please I will appreciate any assistance on how to be able to retrieve these claims anywhere else throughout the application.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework. if yes then it version please.

Comment: Yes. EF 6. Vs 2015. ASP.NET MVC

Comment: which identity version are you using

Comment: Identity version is 2.2.1

Comment: I feel ya on this. The worst.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You must add your claims **before** login not after. Consider this example:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model,string returnUrl)
{
    var user = UserManager.Find(model.Email, model.Password);
    if(user!=null)
    {
        var ident = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, 
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        ident.AddClaims(new[] {
            new Claim("MyClaimName","MyClaimValue"),
            new Claim("YetAnotherClaim","YetAnotherValue"),
        });
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
            new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, 
            ident);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Now since we have injected our claims while signing in, we have access to claims wherever we want:

```
((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("MyClaimName");
```

Also you could add your claims in `ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync()` method. By adding your claims in this method you could use `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` method to sign in users without any modification to default `Login` action method.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity .AddClaims(new[] {
            new Claim("MyClaimName","MyClaimValue"),
            new Claim("YetAnotherClaim","YetAnotherValue"),
        });
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sam, Thank you but I tried it with no success. The claims were still not available except the claims that are stored in the database table which are the ones I added to the user while registering the user. Other ones I added the way you suggested above, were not available in other parts of the application. Could there be any configuration needed at web.config or something else?

Comment: Have you configured Cookie Authentication in `ConfigureAuth` method?

Comment: I am not familiar with how to go about that. Could you provide a guide please? I think that may be where I am still missing something important

Comment: Have look at [my sample repo](https://github.com/samfgl/TokenBasedAuthenticationSample). It would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Sam, the approach you suggested above (i.e. putting the new claims in ApplicationUser class worked. I later got it working that way and now I have my claims set after login and I can find it after login. Thank you very much. I am very grateful for your support

Comment: I am so happy hear that. Please accept as a right answer so everybody else with same problem could find the answer more easily.

Comment: can you add a github sample for asp mvc 5 , identity 2.2

Comment: Saved my day! Few of them! =) Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In identity 2, this is done very differently and simply by creating a claims principal factory and then hooking it up in your startup ConfigureServices as below...

```
public class CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IUser, IApplicationRole>
{
    public CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<IUser> userManager, RoleManager<IApplicationRole> roleManager,
                                                IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(IUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

        // Add your claims here
        ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                                                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Gender, user.Gender),
                                                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
                                                                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName)
                                                             });

        return principal;
    }
}
```

You would then hook it up in ConfigureServices just after calling AddIdentity like this...

```
         services.AddIdentity<IUser, IApplicationRole>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        // Add Custom Claims processor
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IUser>, CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Here is a very good article on the subject...

https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/security/asp.net-core-and-claim-based-security.html

Answer (score 4):

Then in the view page

```
@(((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirstValue("firstName"))
```

It will show the authenticated user firstName.

and import the following packages at the top of the page

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using System.Security.Claims;
```

Comment: did you have value in the user claims table

Comment: The value in the user claims table is the only claim I created while registering the user. And that is the one that I can access from anywhere in the application. The others that I add after successful login, are not added to the table and they are not accessible

Comment: dude you should add data to user claims while user registration only not while login. for single user there should be single record only.

Comment: import the two packages in the view page '@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity'
'@using System.Security.Claims;'

Comment: to enter the user details in db whenever user login, then session should be used and it stores the user details while login. User claims table is used to store user details when the user is created and to show the details in every page

Answer (score 1):

are you not able to access `User.Identity` from the view?

To retrieve claims for a user, it's been as simple as this for me:

`var identity = (ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity`

And then accessing `identity.Claims` and using LINQ to retrieve specific claims.

Comment: Yea. But I tried that and I couldnt get any result other than an empty string. but when I do same on the Login controller after adding the claim, I get the claim value returned to me. `var email = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();` and when I try to retrieve email, it is empty

Comment: Okay, well your current code doesn't show that. Are you trying to access a user's claims before login?

Comment: When debugging, are there any claims available in your ClaimsIdentity?

Comment: I am not trying to access the claims before login. Its after. No other claims except those I added while creating the user. That is  GivenName. If I try to retieve that one, It returns the expected value

Comment: are you adding more claims after the user is created and signed in?

Comment: Yes. The claims are added after successfully logging in

Comment: and they are added to the Claims table?

Comment: No. I am not adding them to the claims table. I expect them to be stored in cookies for better performance on retrieval during request. Added to the fact that it is meant to be dynamic. And so can change at next login. So, storing it in table would require removing it from there at logout too. I feel it doesn't have to be stored in table . but maybe I haven't been able to store it properly in cookie. Maybe that's where I may need to be guided now

Comment: this code won't work if these CLAIMS do not exist in your CLAIMS table..  but like anand said below, you should be adding these claims during registration. why are you trying to add claims during login? my thought is you should add claims during registration, pull them out of the table after login, and store them in cookies while the session is maintained.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for that advice. However, I wish to know, does it mean that if the claims are not in the table, they can't be stored in cookie and maintained in the session? Because I feel if it can be stored in cookie after being pulled from the table, then it should as well be possible to store it in the cookie from a list

Comment: no it doesn't mean a claim can't be stored. but if they're not in the table and you're trying to pull out claims using `ClaimsIdentity`, they won't exist.

Comment: Okay @terbubbs, My main aim in trying to store them only in cookies and session is to avoid hitting the database on every request to check for some privileges of the logged in user. As such, I wish to fetch all the privileges of the logged in user and store them in session for peroformance reasons.

Comment: well you should be getting those claims at login and then storing them in your cookies and session. how are you going to persist them after they log out?

Comment: I don't need to persist them on logout. They should be discarded on logout. Could you pls provide a guide on how to store the claims in cookie/session. I think that's where I am still getting something wrong.

Comment: you could easily make a model storing the data you need, then store it in session and retrieve it using the `User.Identity.GetUserId` value.

Answer (score 0):

The Claim property from IdentityUser gives you an ICollection with that collection you can call the following C# method:

```
    public string GetCustomClaimValue(ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> claimCollection, string customClaimType)
    {
        string claimValue = "";
        foreach (IdentityUserClaim claim in claimCollection)
        {
            if (claim.ClaimType == customClaimType)
            {
                claimValue = claim.ClaimValue;
                break;
            }
        }
        return claimValue;
    }
```