# Select tenant after login preventing user to use the system before that

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, two-factor-authentication

**I want to something like:**

- After user logged in open a view to select the Tenant that user will use to work. But I want to prevent user to access the system without set the Tenant.

**Details:**

- I need the tenant selection to be in a second page different of the login page, because I want to show only the Tenants that have relashionship with this user.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: You could use ajax to call server method that returns the collection of Tenants based on the UserName and add it to the DOM (as a dropdownlist?) so the user can select a Tenant in the login form, then add a `ClaimsIdentity` that can be used for authorization (refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153541/add-claims-on-successful-login-and-retrieve-it-elsewhere-in-the-application) for a example of adding the claim