# How to assign a user manually

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have all the claims and i have also checked if the token is valid. How do i `signin` this new user with `IsAuthenticated=true` and the claims principals

```
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(conf.GetSection("JWTKey").Value)),
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false
            }
            ;

            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            IPrincipal pr= tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

            var claims = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token).Claims;
            var claimspr = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(cliams,"JWTAuth"));
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153541/add-claims-on-successful-login-and-retrieve-it-elsewhere-in-the-application

Comment: `AuthenticationManager` doesnt have a `signin` method

Comment: Is your AuthenticationManager implemented like this?  private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager {
        get {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

Comment: Oh I was using the class ‘AuthenticationManager’  not the interface. Is there any other way to do this? ‘IAuthenticationManager’ yells at me saying its not compatible with my application. Tried installing the older versions didnt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using .net core. You can use `HttpContext.SignInAsync`and pass `ClaimsPrincipal` as a param.See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0)