# i logged in but i want to display part of table on the next page based on employee department (user table contains foreign key of department)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Account class

```
//Account class
public class Register
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "كلمة المرور غير مطابقة")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        public int? DepartId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartId")]
        public virtual Department Depart { get; set; }

    }
public partial class Fax
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }

    public string From { get; set; }

    public string FaxDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FaxDate { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

}
```

Add Razor page for Register

```
//Add Razor page for Register


namespace Archives.Pages
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ArchivesDbContext context;

        [BindProperty]
        public Register Model { get; set; }
        public RegisterModel( Archives.Models.ArchivesDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(context.Departments, "Id", "DepartmentName");
            Model = new Register();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            Model.Password = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(Model.Password);
            context.registers.Add(Model);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("/Fax/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

register.cshtml

```
\\register.cshtml

`<section class="h-100 h-custom" style="background-color: #8fc4b7;">
    <div class="container py-5 h-100">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
                <div class="card rounded-3">
                    <img src="/images/Picture1.jpg"
                         class="w-100" style="border-top-left-radius: .3rem; border-top-right-radius: .3rem;"
                         alt="Sample photo">
                    <div class="card-body p-4 p-md-5">


                        <form class="px-md-2" method="post">
                            <div style="text-align:right;" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Model.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <br />
                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">

                                <label asp-for="Model.UserName" class="control-label" style="display:flex">أسم المستخدم</label>
                                <input asp-for="Model.UserName" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Model.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <br />
                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">

                                <label asp-for="Model.Password" class="control-label" style="display:flex">كلمة المرور</label>
                                <input type="password" asp-for="Model.Password" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Model.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <br />
                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">

                                <label asp-for="Model.ConfirmPassword" class="control-label" style="display:flex">تأكيد كلمة المرور</label>
                                <input type="password" asp-for="Model.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Model.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                <select style="width:250px;" asp-for="Model.DepartId" class="select form-control-lg" asp-items="@ViewBag.DepartmentId">
                                    <option value="">اختر القسم المختص</option>
                                </select>



                            </div>

                            <div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mb-1" style="display:flex">تسجيل </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>`
```

Add Razor page for login

```
//Add Razor page for login 
\\login.cshtml.cs

 {
        private readonly ArchivesDbContext db;

        [BindProperty]
       
        public Register account { get; set; }
        public string Message;
      

        public LoginModel(ArchivesDbContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "DepartmentName");
            account = new Register();
        }
        public IActionResult OnGetLogout()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Remove("username");
            return RedirectToPage("Login");
        }
      
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
      
            var acc = login(account.UserName, account.Password);
            if (acc == null)
            {
                Message = "غير مسموح بالدخول";
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
            **    HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", acc.UserName);
              
                return RedirectToPage("/Fax/Index");**
            }
        }
        private Register login(string username,string password)
        {
            var account = db.registers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Equals(username));
            if (account != null)
            {
                if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, account.Password))
                {
                    return account;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```
\\login.cshtml

<section class="h-100 h-custom" style="background-color: #8fc4b7;">
    <div class="container py-5 h-100">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-6">
                <div class="card rounded-3">
                    <img src="/images/Picture1.jpg"
                         class="w-100" style="border-top-left-radius: .3rem; border-top-right-radius: .3rem;"
                         alt="Sample photo">
                    <div class="card-body p-4 p-md-5">


                        <form class="px-md-2" method="post" >
                            <div style="text-align:right;" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="account.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <br />
                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">

                                <label asp-for="account.UserName" class="control-label" style="display:flex">أسم المستخدم</label>
                                <input asp-for="account.UserName" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="account.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                            <br />
                            <div class="form-outline mb-4">

                                <label asp-for="account.Password" class="control-label" style="display:flex">كلمة المرور</label>
                                <input type="password" asp-for="account.Password" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                      




                            <input  asp-action="OnPostAsync" type="submit" value="تسجيل الدخول" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mb-1" style="display:flex">
                       
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

when  redirect to page /Fax/Index want to filter all faxes with the user department not all faxes

no proplem with me in login and logout and registeration .. just i want each employee (user) to see only his faxes not all faxes

Comment: Add a claim to the user when they log in for their DepartmentId and use that to filter your database query for the faxes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153541/add-claims-on-successful-login-and-retrieve-it-elsewhere-in-the-application

Comment: Where is your fax? Could you pls share more code with your model?

Comment: Thank You Rena so much .. your answer solved My problem but I want Two other things .. first i want nav bar to appear after login in the layout page .. second i want specific users with their specific deparment to have all faxes table .. Thanks Again @Rena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is model design, but you can get the fax by the username session. Here is a simple demo you could follow:

Model

```
public class Register
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "كلمة المرور غير مطابقة")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public int? DepartId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartId")]
    public virtual Department Depart { get; set; }

}
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartName { get; set; }
    public List<Fax> Faxes { get; set; }
}
public class Fax
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

PageModel

```
public List<Fax> Faxes{ get; set; }
public void OnGet()
{
     Faxes = db.Registers.Include(a => a.Depart).ThenInclude(a => a.Faxes)
                        .SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == HttpContext.Session.GetString("username"))?
                        .Depart.Faxes;
}
```